# Multiprocessing code in a game isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

My problem is that when I do a multiprocessing code it isn't working for a script I wrote.
The code I am writing is for a clicker game by the way.

Here's the code I tried. What I was hopping it would do was to open a Tk window, which it does, but the part that's wrong is every 0.6 seconds 1 is added to score, but that isn't happening. The part that isn't working is the def autopoints and bellow that

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import multiprocessing
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
score = 0
PointsPerClick = 10
PriceForUpgrade = 100
pointsfromautogen = 1
timeforautogen = 0.6
priceforautogen = 500
pricefortimeautogen = 2000
root.title("Clicker Game")
#this is basically the code for the text in the window
scoretext = StringVar()
scoretext.set(score)
score_label = Label(root, textvariable = scoretext)
upgradecosttext = StringVar()
upgradecosttext.set(PriceForUpgrade + 10)
upgradecost_label = Label(root, textvariable = upgradecosttext)
pointsperclicktext = StringVar()
pointsperclicktext.set(PointsPerClick)
pointsperclicktext_label = Label(root, textvariable = pointsperclicktext)
pointsfromautogentext = StringVar()
pointsfromautogentext.set(pointsfromautogen)
pointsfromautogentext_label = Label(root, textvariable = pointsfromautogentext)
#code for the buttons
def bAaction():
    global score
    score += PointsPerClick
    scoretext.set(score)
def bBaction():
    global score
    global PriceForUpgrade
    if score > PriceForUpgrade:
        global PointsPerClick
        score -= PriceForUpgrade
        PointsPerClick += 5
        PriceForUpgrade += 150
        upgradecosttext.set(PriceForUpgrade + 1)
        pointsperclicktext.set(PointsPerClick)
    else:
        print('Not enough. Need more score')
def bCaction():
        global pointsfromautogen
        global priceforautogen
            if score > priceforautogen:
                pointsfromautogen += 10
                pointsfromautogentext.set(priceforautogen + 1)
                priceforautogen += 100
#code for the auto generator (aka the part that isn't working)
def autopoints():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    score + pointsfromautogen
    scoretext.set(score)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ap = multiprocessing.Process(target=autopoints)
    ap.start()
    ap.join()

def bDaction():
    if score < pricefortimeautogen:
        if timeforautogen > 0.5:
                timeforautogen - 0.1
                pricefortimeautogen + 2000
        else:
            print('At max level or not enough points')
#all of the buttons
buttonA = Button(root, text='Points Generator', command=bAaction)
buttonB = Button(root, text='Upgrade', command=bBaction)
buttonC = Button(root, text ='Auto Points Upgrade', command=bCaction)
buttonD = Button(root, text='Speed Up Auto Points', command=bDaction)


#just packing everything needed
buttonA.pack()
buttonB.pack()
buttonC.pack()
buttonD.pack()
score_label.pack()
upgradecost_label.pack()
pointsperclicktext_label.pack()
pointsfromautogentext_label.pack()
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you should be using `threading.Thread` instead of `multiprocessing`.

Comment: You should generalize your code example. Rather than wanting us to read through all the details of your specific project, you should narrow down the *sort* of problem happening, and give a minimal toy example of it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).